# Adding a text area to only one page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a website using ReactJS. I want to add a textarea to only one of the pages. Each page has a header and a content tag. If I put the code in App.js, it will show up on each page:

```
import react from 'react';


import Header from './Header.js';

class App extends react.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header />
            <Content />
         </div>
      );
   }
}


 
    class Content extends react.Component {
       render() {
          return (
             <div>


           <h1 className='center bold'>Hi</h1>
           <textarea id='editor' rows="25" cols="90"></textarea>

         </div>
      );

       }
    }

    export default App;
```

Then I have the webpage Javascript, Code.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and then the HTML Markup, code.html:

Create

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <content></content>
  <div>
  <textarea id='editor' rows="25" cols="90">
  </textarea>
</div>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

I have tried to put the textarea in a number of different places with no success. It either doesn't render or it renders on ever page.

How do I go about getting this to appear only on the page I want it to?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a state value in App.js, like - this.state = {currentPage: "<page no 1>"}
Then write a function in App.js to change this state value.
pageChangeHandler = (value) ={ this.setState({currentPage: val})}.
Now pass this.state.currentPage and this.pageChangeHandler to each of the 5 pages as props..
Inside the page where you want to put textarea, check using currentPage from props.
And on change of page please call the function this.props.pageChangeHandler() and pass current page.
I hope this resolves your problem! Please let me know!